# DocuSign API Can't download signed PDFs USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP Error

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the envelopes list status changes api and getting the error below. I am the only user on the account and a DS Admin. Also, we have used this code successfully with other DocuSign accounts.

Can you please help me resolve the issue?

Error:
ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response

Body:

```
'{"errorCode":"USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP","message":"The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account."}'


ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.setAccessToken(token, tokenExpirationSeconds);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
// prepare the request body
EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions options = envelopesApi.new ListStatusChangesOptions();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(30);
options.setFromDate(date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

// call the API - ERROR HERE
`EnvelopesInformation results = envelopesApi.listStatusChanges(accountId, options);`

Answer (score 0):

the userId you used for your JWT token must be an admin of the same exact account in DocuSign.
Any chance you use demo vs. production? two different accounts?
This error simply means your API calls is using a user that is not authorized to view this envelope because it lacks a membership to the account that this envelope is part of.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of that error (after you've confirmed the account ID is correct) is hitting the wrong Base URL for the account. The first time you generate an authentication token for a particular user, you should make a UserInfo call and cache the BaseURL value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Ended up rebuilding credentials from scratch. I appreciate the insights.